# S.S. Pillai on Consecutive integers research paper?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

I am trying to prove:

> Given any seventeen consecutive integers, there does not exist one which is coprime to the rest.

I am aware S.S.Pillai proved a similar statement for $m$ consecutive integers, where $17\leqslant m \leqslant  430$. I can't seem to find the proof online. Does anyone know where I can find the proof?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I believe that.  I can find 17 consecutive integers with no primes,  I can find the largest prime below those 17.  Then a can chose 17 around the prime.  That prime will be coprime to the rest.  So what am I misinterpreting.

Comment: @fleablood, see introduction to http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~saradha/st-proc-r-f2.pdf   Meanwhile, some of the more recent proofs might be available online. Papers from the 1940's, maybe not.

Comment: @fleablood Let $S$ be the set of seventeen consecutive integers. Can you find an $x$ $\in$ $S$ such that $x$ is comprime is to the rest of the numbers in the set.

Comment: I think the statement should be "there **exists** a set of 17 consecutive integers, none of which is coprime to the rest".

Comment: 18! +2 to 18! + 18! are 17 consecutive integers. None of them are prime. Let p be the largest prime less than 18! + 2. Obviously p > 17 so p- 8 to p+8 will be 17 consecutive integers. p is coprime to all the rest. In fact, Geez, any 17 containing a prime greater than 17.

Comment: @WillJagy, I've come across this paper before but it only proves that the statement doesn't hold for $m$ $\leqslant$ 16

Comment: Robert isreal.  That would make more sense.

Comment: Lets look at a set of five consecutive integers. Then we can always find one number in the set which will be coprime to the rest of the number.

For example for sequence
$n$,$n+1$,$n+2$,$n+3$,$n+4$

if n is even and n+1 is not divisible by 3 then $n+1$ is coprime to the rest of the numbers.

Does it hold for 17 consecutive integers?

Comment: @Nadia It does not, see my answer (or the first page of the article Will Jagy linked to!). However, this doesn't mean that *every* set of 17 consecutive integers *doesn't* contain an element coprime to the others - e.g. if there's a prime amongst the 17 integers (as per fleablood's comment).

Comment: Nadia.  Apparently there does exist infinite sets of 17 consecutive where I will not be able to find a number coprime to the rest.  But that isn't true for all sets of 17 consecutive numbers.  Any set of consecutive numbers containing a significantly large prime will have a the prime coprime.

Comment: 1-17.  11,13,17 are coprime to all others.  18-34.  19, 23, 29, 31 are co prime to all others.  The first list where this isn't true probably consists of quite large numbers.  But apparent infinitely many  do exist.  I think that, rather than what you stated is what you want to prove.

Comment: @fleablood At https://oeis.org/A090318/internal, they say the shortest such sequence begins with 2184. Large, but not as large as I was expecting!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Not as large as I was expecting either.  Large enough to have a prime-free sequence of 17 (that first occurs at 523).  I was almost expecting it to be about 17!.

Comment: I tried to find such a sequence and found from 27830-27846, but I guess that's not even the smallest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be garbling Pillai's result. Using the noation of http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~saradha/st-proc-r-f2.pdf (and indeed everything in my answer is taken from the first page of that paper), say a set $S$ has *property $P_1$* if there is some $x\in S$ which is coprime to all other elements of $S$. Pillai proved two things:

- Any set of consecutive integers with *fewer* than 17 elements has property $P_1$.
- For $17\le m\le 430$, there are *infinitely many* sets $S$ of $m$-many consecutive integers where $S$ does **not** have property $P_1$. EDIT: The first example is the sequence of length $17$, starting with $2184$ (see https://oeis.org/A090318/internal).

Note that as fleablood says, what you've written is false for any $n>1$ at all: if $X$ is a set of $n$-many consecutive integers with largest element prime, then $p$ is coprime to all other elements of $X$.

(Note that it is not enough for $X$ to merely contain *a* prime - e.g. in $\{2, 3, 4, . . . , 18\}$, $2$ is prime but not coprime to the other elements!)

---

Note: Pillay later extended the second clause to $17\le m\le 12335$. Scott then extended this to $17\le m\le 2491906561$, and then finally Brauer got the full result: if $17\le m$, then there are infinitely many sets $S$ consisting of $m$-many consecutive integers, such that $S$ does not have property $P_1$. So the full result is:

- If I have a set $S$ of $m$-many consecutive integers for $m<17$, then there is an element of $S$ which is coprime to the others.
- However, I'm not guaranteed to be able to pull this off for $m\ge 17$; indeed, there will be infinitely many counterexamples (although of course there are also sets of arbitrarily many consecutive integers which *do* contain an element coprime to the others, namely any set containing at least one prime).

---

As for proofs, Brauer's paper (proving the full result) is publicly available at https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183503578; Pillai's original papers "On $M$ consecutive integers I-IV" seem harder to find.

Comment: I see my mistake. So to be clear, there do exist 17 consecutive integers where the property holds?

Comment: @Nadia Indeed - take, for instance, $\{3, 4, 5, . . , 18, 19\}$. Then $19$ is coprime to all the other elements.

Comment: p is coprime to all other elements of X if p < n. Obviously if 2p is in X...

Comment: Thank you for clearing my confusion.

I will have a read of Brauer's paper. Yes Pillai's orginal papers is a hard find. I can't seem to get hold of them.

Comment: @fleablood I think you mean if $n<p$. But it's also enough to just make the top element prime.

Comment: See also OEIS sequence [A090318](https://oeis.org/A090318) and references there.

Comment: Out of interest. Can anyone think of a 17 consecutive integers sequence where this property does not hold?

Comment: @Nadia, the wording in your question is still incorrect, even after your edit of about four minutes ago. It is not ***any*** interval of 17 consecutive numbers.

Comment: @Nadia Quoting from https://oeis.org/A090318/internal: "The shortest stapled interval has length 17 and starts with the number 2184." ("Stapled interval" means "interval with no element which is coprime to the others.")

Comment: So I think what Nadia wishes to prove is that there is a sequence where the property doesn't hold.  Does anyone know of one?

Comment: @fleablood See my comment immediately above yours . . . (now added to my answer).

Comment: @NoahSchweber  Yes, I meant p > n although p > 1/2 n is works to if the first half are below.  I guess as long as the last of the consecutive numbers is less than 2p would have been the best way to put it.  It's interesting to know the first starts at 2184.  I hadn't been familiar with this theorem before.  Not sure why comments were not appearing on my browser.  'caused me to make a lot of redundant comments and questions.