# One of any consecutive integers is coprime to the rest

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

After reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720234/proof-check-given-any-five-consecutive-integers-there-is-always-one-which-is-r), I conjectured a generalization of it.

> **Conjecture:**        Fix  $k\in \mathbb N$. Then, for all $n\in \mathbb N$, one of $n+1,\ldots,n+k$ is coprime to the rest.

I tried some elementary ways, but wasn't successful.

**Observation:** One of the consequences of this conjecture is that there are infinitely many primes!

Comment: I assume you meant k>1. Answer below is surprising to me.

Comment: @user254665 If k=1, $n+1$ is coprime to all members of $\varnothing$ !

Comment: You got me on that one.:).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Surprisingly, the statement is *false* once $k\ge17$, and the shortest counterexample is the sequence of length $17$ beginning with $2184$. This was the result of a line of work beginning with Pillai, and finally wrapped up by Brauer. See [S.S. Pillai on Consecutive integers research paper?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699375/s-s-pillai-on-consecutive-integers-research-paper/1699384#1699384).

- Pillai showed that it holds for $k<17$, but can fail for all $k$ between $17$ and $430$ - infinitely often, in fact!
- In a sequence of results, this was improved until eventually Scott showed that there are infinitely many counterexamples for $17\le k\le 2491906561$ . . .
- . . . and then Brauer showed that there are infinitely many counterexamples for *any* $k\ge 17$.

Comment: Thanks, it's amazing! Because I thought this conjecture is trivially true!

Comment: https://oeis.org/A090318/internal

Comment: I posted this observation at [Examples of eventual counterexamples](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15444/examples-of-eventual-counterexamples/234875#234875) in MO.

Comment: I would have expected a short elementary  decision. Number theory is full of deceptively simple-sounding hard Q's.